# I cant edit and view posts in cakePhp tutorial

Tags: php, cakephp

I watched cakePhp blog totorial and I  have done all steps, but it shows error:

> Error in: ROOT/src/Template/Posts/view.ctp, line 1
>   Could this be caused by using Auto-Tables?

Some of the Table objects in your application were created by instantiating `Cake\ORM\Table` instead of any other specific subclass.

This could be the cause for this exception. Auto-Tables are created for you under the following circumstances:

The class for the specified table does not exist.
The Table was created with a typo:

```
TableRegistry::get('Atricles');
```

The class file has a typo in the name or incorrect namespace: class Atricles extends Table.
The file containing the class has a typo or incorrect casing: Atricles.php
The Table was used using associations but the association has a typo:

```
$this->belongsTo('Atricles');
```

The table class resides in a Plugin but no plugin notation was used in the association definition.

Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:

Posts

I see my posts(which have been added in console), but I can't see one post, edit and add new.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your Table object in your model is the same name as your table in your database. In this case your database table should be named articles. If you want to use a different database table in your model you can use this in your table object:

```
$this->table('my_table');
```

You can read more about this on their website: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html